# Script works at jsFiddle but not in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have this Greasemonkey script that works fine in the Fiddle. It's designed to capitalize the text entered in an input field. Unfortunately, when I try to implement it into Greasemonkey, it refuses to work.

Can anybody help me? I'm new at Greasemonkey.

The script (It's also at [this jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/pSnqR/):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           2
// @include        *
// @require        http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
$(document).ready(function(){
$.fn.capitalize = function () {
    $.each(this, function () {
        var split = this.value.split(' ');
        for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
            split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
        }
        this.value = split.join(' ');
    });
    return this;
};

$('input').on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).capitalize();
}).capitalize();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. The problem is probably an install conflict.  The script from that jsFiddle does nominally work as a GM script.

   1. From the "Manage User Scripts" panel, uninstall the current script and any others with the same name.
   2. Restarting Firefox would also be a good idea.
   3. Save the code, below, to `Capitalize_Inputs.user.js` and then install it as a Greasemonkey script.  (Adjust the `include`, `exclude`, and `match` directives.)
2. You do not need to use `$(document).ready()` here or in most GM scripts.
3. Avoid using `@include  *` if you can.  It speed things up and reduces potential conflicts.
4. That `capitalize()` function could be better.  At a minimum, replace:
   `var split = this.value.split(' ');`
   with:
   `var split = this.value.split(/\s/);`  // Or split(/\s+/) depending on if multiple spaces desired

The resulting script would be like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Capitalize inputs
// @include  http://YOUR_SITE/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$.fn.capitalize = function () {
    $.each(this, function () {
        var split = this.value.split (/\s+/);
        for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
            split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
        }
        this.value = split.join (' ');
    } );
    return this;
};

$('input').on ('keyup', function () {
    $(this).capitalize ();
} ).capitalize();
```

Comment: 2, and 3 are valid.  4 is reasonable, but it will change the string (besides capitalizing it).  However, only 1.1 is potentially relevant to the issue.  It is not necessary to change the name or restart Firefox.  It is possible to install, uninstall, and even change installed scripts, while Firefox is running.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen: No it is not strictly necessary to change the name, but it may very well be necessary to restart FF.  The name change is just a technique that has proven to help new users when dealing with install conflicts.  The restart helps to resolve additional conflicts and erratic behavior that crop up when doing a lot of live-editing and debugging of GM scripts.  You'll also notice that FF bloats its memory usage at an accelerated rate when debugging GM scripts, and FF slows down.  Both good reasons for a restart.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen, your point about changing the string is valid.  I doubt if it is an issue but it's easily fixed. edited the answer. Much more importantly, the old code flat-out did not work when words where preceded by anything other than an ordinary space.  Tabs, returns, non-breaking space, unicode spaces, etc, all would cause it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.  Firefox 10.0.2, Greasemonkey 0.9.18.  I'm using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzgn9/1/), which is just an input (no library), to test.

Try to uninstall then reinstall the script.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.  (Haven't flagged it yet.)

Comment: @BrockAdams, my answer is that there is nothing wrong with the script.  If I hadn't actually tested, I would have posted it as a comment.  I've added a note about reinstalling.  I'm also glad to follow up if the OP indicates they've retested.